# Best image hosting service

Tags: media, images, hosting, cdn

My girlfriend has a very popular blog, but we are growing beyond current bandwidth limit (1TB). Adsense doesn't pay enough for an expensive CDN.

What recommendations can you make about image hosting. Preferably a plugin, or something that can easily be implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not recommended often enough, but Flickr is an excellent image host for blogs as well. Their pro account costs only $25/year. You get unlimited image, video uploads and no bandwidth limit.

If you don't want your blog image uploads populating your personal photostream, you can easily create a separate account for it. You can easily streamline your uploading and insertion process by using plugins like [Flickr Photo Album for Wordpress](http://www.johnchow.com/how-to-add-flickr-images-on-your-blog/) , Flickrpress , Alternative WordPress Image Uploader Using Flickr . Or you can do it the old-fashioned [manual way](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_host_blog_images_on_flickr.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to go a more budget route, you can use Amazon S3 (storage) with Amazon CloudFront (CDN). New subscribers get 5 GB/month of free storage for a year. With Amazon, you pay for only the amount of bandwidth you use. Typically 15 cents/GB (depending on service and location).

Couple that with the W3 Total Cache plugin and it should be a relatively simple thing to setup.

Or [MaxCDN](http://www.maxcdn.com/) is currently offering 1 TB of bandwidth for $39.95/month (typically $99).

Comment: Is there a way to only do a portion of your files? S3 will cost over $100/mo extra, and adsense definitely doesn't pay enough for that.

Comment: CloudFront transfer isn't free. Also there is away to only do a portition but it would mean alot of work.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is just to move to a hoster who gives you more bandwidth. That said you have a few options.

1. Dropbox -http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropbox-cdn/ - pretty much cheap and cheerful
2. Smushit - Basically decrease the size of the images.
3. Do image hosting on free image hosters, however this will result in your images constantly being deleted and possibly being blacklisted from image hosters.
4. Move hosters, hosters like OVH.co.uk offer unlimited bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I've used IMGUR plugin before and it worked without a hitch.

Here's the plugin.

http://wp.am/imgur/

Comment: Please Note that imgur photos will not stay persistent unless you choose a payment plan. The free hosted is limited in terms of time and usage.